# Text Processing and pd.get_dummies() Encoding Consumes huge amount of RAM

Tags: python, pandas, text, encoding

I am having a dataset consisting of tokenized and stemmed words in a list and I am using `pd.get_dummies()` to encode them. The problem is that my dataset is rather large having 2054735 words of which only 257 are unique. The problem is when I start applying the `pd.get_dummies()`, I can't use more than 257 words otherwise my kernel crashes because it runs out of memory > 13Gb. I have checked the memory usage of the resulting dataframe and for 7055x257 is only 1.8MB.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_balanced_features = pd.Series([["one", "home", "dark"], ["hello", "gamma", "hello"], ["five", "tango", "bravo"]])

df_balanced_features = pd.get_dummies(df_balanced_features.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level = 0)
```

[image]

Any idea, how I can use `pd.get_dummies` to encode more than 250 columns?

Comment: Are you able to run this to completion with a smaller dataset? If so, can you run it and monitor if the memory usage to see if it drops after it finished running? I'm curious whether it's the final data frame that taking too much ram or one of the intermediate steps.

Comment: the resulting dataframe is very small with around 300 unique words, it is about 2 MB in size. So apparently this excessive RAM usage is happening on one of the intermediate steps. I have tried to run the same code on another laptop also with 16Gb of RAM but I had the same problem.

Comment: It appear the method you have now is creating an extra dimension (ie, ```(n_row, vocab_size, sentence_length)```) then summing across each sentence to get the number of occurrences of each word. It's not actually a 3-dimensional array since you are using ```pd.DataFrame.stack()``` to convert one of the dimensions into a second index but it uses the same amount of memory. The way around creating an extra dimension is to make dictionary of words outside of your DataFrame and use that to count the words in each document. All the solutions so far are doing some form of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses `Counter` from the built-in collections `package` -- it may have a smaller memory usage than the solution you presented.  I used `dtype="Int8"`, which is an 8-bit pandas integer type that supports null (NaN) values.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

data = [["one", "home", "dark"], 
        ["hello", "gamma", "hello"], 
        ["five", "tango", "bravo"]]

words = ( Counter(d) for d in data )
df = pd.DataFrame(words, dtype="Int8").fillna(0).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

print(df)

   bravo  dark  five  gamma  hello  home  one  tango
0      0     1     0      0      0     1    1      0
1      0     0     0      1      2     0    0      0
2      1     0     1      0      0     0    0      1
```

Comment: What is the big O complexity for this solution?

Answer (score 1):

It´s possible to get the dummies manually, but are necessary the following steps. 
This proccess requires a low quantity of memory product of the iteration in the creation of the columns of dummies

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_balanced_features = pd.Series([["one", "home", "dark", "bravo"], ["hello", "gamma", "hello"], ["five", "tango", "bravo"]])
```

Get the unique strings

```
unique_values = []
for values in df_balanced_features:
  for value in values:
    if value not in unique_values:
      unique_values.append(value)
```

Count the frequencies of each string in every list on the Series (is similar to level=0)

```
  total_rows = list()
    for column in unique_values:
      row = list()
      for values in df_balanced_features:
        number = values.count(column)
        row.append(number)
      total_rows.append(row)
```

Traspose the total_rows

```
    total_rows = np.array(total_rows)
    total_rows = total_rows.transpose()
```

Create a DataFrame similar to dummies

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(total_rows, columns = unique_values)
    df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the gensim package for tasks like these and I've never ran into an issue with running out of memory. Atleast during this step. NLP can be memory intensive!

```
import gensim
from gensim import corpora

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(df_balanced_features.tolist())
dummy_encoded = df_balanced_features.apply(lambda doc: pd.Series(dict(dictionary.doc2bow(doc)))).fillna(0).astype(int)
dictionary.id2token[0]  # id2token is lazy so you need to call it once to create it in memory
dummy_encoded.rename(columns=dictionary.id2token, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The dictionary is empty when I call `dictionary.id2token` it returns me an empty dictionary

Comment: Did you run this line and read my comment? ```dictionary.id2token[0]  # id2token is lazy so you need to call it once to create it in memory```

Comment: yes, I run the line but it says that the dictionary is empty. It crashes on the third line and when I call `dictionary.id2token` it returns an empty dictionary `{}` and that index 0 doesn't exist